# I am misunderstanding the "this" keyworld in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this

```
var string5 = "string five outside";

alert( string5 );

function magical( )
{
    this.string5 = "string five INSIDE";

    alert( string5 ); 
    alert( this.string5 ); 
}

magical( );
```

I thought alert( string5 ); would display "string five outside" and alert (this.string5); would display "string five INSIDE" because when we put this. notation in front of a JavaScript variable within a function, that variable becomes exclusive to the JavaScript function which also serves as an object, but alert( this.string5) is still associated with the string5 variable outside the function

Comment: There's no special scope or instance, the function is declared and called in the same scope that `this` would reference inside the function.

Comment: if you did `alert(this.string5)` or `alert(string5)` outside function `magical()` you would get your "expected" result. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Comment: @Vikram I tried this

var zee5 = "Variable Outside";

//alert( this.zee );

function magical( )
{
 this.zee5 = "Inside Function With This";
 alert( this.zee5 ); // "Zee Inside Function With This";
}
magical( );

alert( zee5 );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not binding `this` to anything, it will be bound to the global host object. The very same one that hosts global variables.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyword inside a function for JavaScript refers to the `object` that is bound to the function at the time it is called.

It can be sometimes difficult to predict what that object is if the function is used as a callback. In your example the `this` reference is likely the `window` global object from the web browser.

For example;

```
window.string5 = "hello";
function foo() {
   alert(this.string5);
}
foo();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M5aeE/

`foo()` displays "hello" because `this` was bound to the current object that calls `foo()` which was `window`.

We can override this behavior like so.

```
window.string5 = "hello";
var myObj = {string5:"World!"};
function foo() {
   alert(this.string5);
};
var woo = foo.bind(myObj);
woo();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M5aeE/1/

As you can see I used `bind(myObj)` to change what `this` references.

The keywords `this` and `new` in Javascript do not behave the same way they do in other languages, because of this it can be tricky to understand.

It's good practice to use `bind` when you need to be sure of what `this` references.

As an example;

```
 $("button").on('click',function() {
       // do stuff with this
 }.bind(this));
```

By default, jQuery will bind the DOM element that triggers events to `this`. You can override this by setting your own `this` reference..